# Understanding basic behavioural Verilog: simple RAM module

Tags: digital-logic, verilog

My interest is more in what the actual synthesized circuit will look like, and what components it will be built from. Here is an example 64x1 RAM module:

```
module ram64X1 (clk, we, d, addr, q);

   input clk, we, d;
   input [5:0] addr;
   output q;
   reg [63:0] temp;

   always @ (posedge clk)
      if(we)
         temp[addr] <= d;
   assign q = temp[addr];

endmodule
```

Just to make sure I understand the logic: `addr` indexes a particular spot in the 64x1 bit array. It takes the value `d` and places it at that entry, while also returning the old value `q` that was there before. Is this correct?

My main question is what circuits this will translate into if we synthesize with say, a standard cell library. The `reg` object seems to be an array of flip-flops clocked by `clk`. I don't know what logic circuits take `addr[5:0]` and index into this array. A really wide 64-to-1 mux with `addr` as the select wire? I'd also be curious as to how those muxes are built typically.

Comment: Are you missing an "else" before `assign q`?  And I'd sooner expect q to be defined as a register, so the 'assign' statement wouldn't be appropriate.

Comment: Hi, I was reading these notes I found on the web, it's on one of the first few pages: http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs150/sp11/agenda/lec/lec12-proj3.pdf

Comment: Have you compiled and synthesized the module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question depends heavily on the specific technology being targeted. Furthermore, the tools for that that technology will need to decide whether they can use predefined RAM structures or an array of flip-flops based on the behavior you've specified.

In your example, you have a synchronous write operation (the `always` statement), but an asynchronous read (the `assign` statement). In a lot of technologies, this would translate to an array of FFs with enable inputs. The data input and clock input would be connected to all of them, and a 6-to-64 decoder would translate the address bus into individual enable signals. For reading, a separate 64:1 mux, also driven by the address bus would select the output bit.

If you change the behavior to make the read also synchronous, then most technologies will have a RAM structure that can be used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Slightly tangential question - a RAM structure - for a CPU would that be something similar to SRAM cells like used in caches (e.g. with custom sense/amplify circuits)? When I think RAM I think of those "deep" transistors that store charge capacitively and need to be recharged every few ms.

Comment: The latter form of RAM is "DRAM" (dynamic RAM). Synthesized logic would normally use SRAM (static RAM), which requires no refresh. And most FPGAs have dedicated blocks of SRAM that can be used.